# Translate from TAG format to Regex for Corpus

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with a corpus linguistics tool called AntConc, where you have a document where every word is tagged as a part of speech (noun, adjective, etc), and you use specific commands to pull out matches. For example, if I was looking for a noun (which is tagged NN), I would use `*_NN` and it would find every noun in the document.

I need to translate my `*_TAG` syntax into python regex, and I have no idea how to do that. For example, I have a phrase: `*_PP$ *_NN *_DT *_JJ *_NN` (this translates to possessive pronoun, noun, determiner, adjective, noun; it would find things like "her voice an exact duplicate") in TAG format.

How does one go about changing things like that to regex? For now, I'll take just that basic stuff. Later I'll worry about figuring out how to do "or" and "if this then this" and whatnot.

If you need more info about the tags, try searching for POS tags CLAWS, which should give you a list.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: post a sample input along with expected output.

Comment: Hello! Didn't I do that with *_PP$ *_NN *_DT *_JJ *_NN = "possessive pronoun, noun, determiner, adjective, noun; 'her voice an exact duplicate'"? Can you be clearer on what you want? I don't know much about python. Thanks!

Comment: @CarrieOtt it is not clear what you want. do you want to translate TAGs to a more readable form to be more readable using regex? or do you want to build a regex that is equivalent to the POS tags? please add some input and expected output for us to understand.

Comment: Hello! Yes, I want to build a regex that is equivalent to the POS tags. It's just that I have no idea where to even begin with doing that. Sorry for being confusing! The answer below seems to have the input and output examples you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some research and found [this PDF file](http://www.laurenceanthony.net/software/antconc/releases/AntConc343/help.pdf) describing the notion of embedded tags and non-embedded tags. You are looking to find the embedded tags. So if I'm correct the input would be like this right?

> her_PP$ voice_NN an_DT exact_JJ duplicate_NN

Only then in a larger body of text and you don't know the actual words, you just know the `_XX` tags.

In a regex, you have to be more specific then `*`. What you want in the place of the `*` is 1 or more of any character that is part of a word (letters, but could also contain hyphens maybe?). That makes this for the noun:

```
[\w-]+_NN
```

This means a [character class `[...]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of [word characters `\w`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) and the hyphen `-`, [repeated one or more times `+`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), followed by `_NN`.

For the possessive pronoun, it has a `$` in there which has a special meaning in regexes, if you want the *character* `$` and not its special meaning, you need to escape it with a preceding `\` like so:

```
[\w-]+_PP\$
```

Lastly you want to consider which characters are allowed in between the words. Could be just white-space like spaces, tabs and enters, which would be `\s+`. Could also be *"any character that isn't a word character"* to allow periods, commas, quotes, colons, etc. That would be `\W+` (note the upper case `W` to be the opposite of the lowercase `\w`).

Combined this would amount to this:

```
[\w-]+_PP\$\W+[\w-]+_NN\W+[\w-]+_DT\W+[\w-]+_JJ\W+[\w-]+_NN
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/i6mnOsamsRlJavRN)

To do *"an undetermined amount of unknown words"* you would do this:

```
(?:[\w-]+\W+)*?
```

So the part that matches the word `[\w-]+` and the part that goes in between `\W+` are wrapped into a non-capturing group `(?:...)` and that group is said to occur 0 or more times with the `*` but as few times as possible with `?` to avoid **[greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy)**. You can see it **[here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ANNiX3Mh1wdyI4Vk)** and remove or add an X to see it will still match.

Comment: I also seem to have figured out how to add "wildcards," as it were. So for example, if I'm trying to make "her X X X being" appear (with "her" labeled PP$ and "being" labeled VBG), I could use [\w-]+_PP\$\W+[\w-]+_[\w-]\W+[\w-]+_[\w-]\W+[\w-]+_[\w-]\W+[\w-]+_VBG, I think. Is there a simpler way to do that? I would use that in the context of if I didn't know what words came between the two but knew there would be words there. Then again, that only works if there are in fact three words in between. I don't yet know how to tell it "an undetermined amount of unknown words between." Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: To do _"an undetermined amount of unknown words"_ you would do this: `(?:[\w-]+\W+)*?`. So the part that matches the word `[\w-]+` and the part that goes in between `\W+` are wrapped into a non-capturing group `(?:...)` and that group is said to occur 0 or more times with the `*` but as few times as possible with `?` to avoid **[greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy)**. You can see it **[here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ANNiX3Mh1wdyI4Vk)** and remove or add an X to see it will still match.

Comment: Is it possible to do "an unknown number of words not greater than 4 words"? Or I guess if you have it set up to avoid greediness that might not be necessary. Another thing I was noticing was that if I used [\w-]+_NN|NNS\W+[\w-]+_JJ (JJ is adjective), it would find the NN and NNS fine but what followed them was not always JJ. If I took out the | and ran each of them separately, it worked. What's up with that? Did I do the "or" expression wrong?

Comment: If you look at the link in my answer about [repeating](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) you can see the paragraph about limited repetition. For up-to-four you would do `{0,4}` in stead of the `*` (keep the `?` for the greediness problem).

Comment: For the **or** thing, you wanna group the characters that are the either-or options, so `[\w-]+_(?:NN|NNS)` in your case. Now with this specific case you could do `[\w-]+_NNS?` where the `?` makes the last character, **S**, optional. But that wouldn't work if you want for instance _"noun or adjective"_ because those tags are so different. For clarity of would stick to the grouping/alternation.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help! I'll work with all this info and see if I come up with other questions as I go. But this has definitely given me a great start! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome :) If you could click "accept" next to my answer, it help the website and we both get a few points.

Comment: Hello again! So I can't figure out what's wrong with my regex here. I'm trying to find NN or NNS followed by VBG or VVN followed by a comma, so my regex is  [\w-]+_(?:NN|NNS)\W+[\w-]+ _(?:VBG|VVN)\W+[\w-]+ _,  I'm getting no hits, and when I put it into that Debuggex it says that it does not match at the black triangle slider. I'm sure it's something obvious.

Comment: Hi Carrie, I understand you are new here to Stack Overflow. Your last comment is a question pretty different from where we started out, it is common on here to denote a question was answered by accepting the answer you ended up using. This way people with the same question can see this answer too. You can then open a new question for further help with this comma ordeal. If I paste your regex into debuggex I see a few spaces that might trip you over and as well you seem to look for a word that has the comma as a tag, which I doubt is what the input is like, please provide that in a new question

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to do that later today. I appreciate all  your help!

Comment: Hello again! So my new thread is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829132/creating-more-complex-regexes-from-tag-format. Some other people are trying to help, but they don't understand and I can't seem to explain it so that they do. If you feel like joining in, it's there. :)