# Creating more complex regexes from TAG format

Tags: regex, tags, absolute, corpus, phrase

So I can't figure out what's wrong with my regex here. (The original conversation, which includes an explanation of these TAG formats, can be found here: [Translate from TAG format to Regex for Corpus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751807/translate-from-tag-format-to-regex-for-corpus)).

I am starting with a string like this:

> Arms_NNS folded_VVN ,_,

The NNS could also NN, and the VVN could also be VBG. And I just want to find that and other strings with the same tags (NNS or NN followed b VVN or VBG followed by comma).

The following regex is what I am trying to use, but it is not finding anything:

```
[\w-]+_(?:NN|NNS)\W+[\w-]+ _(?:VBG|VVN)\W+[\w-]+ _,
```

Comment: Did Mark's answer help you out in the end? It looks like it did judging by the last comments. If so I'd be nice if you accept his answer **:)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You were both very helpful in solving this problem, and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the input string

```
Arms_NNS folded_VVN ,_,
```

the following regex

```
(\w+_(?:NN|NNS) \w+_(?:VBG|VVN) ,_,)
```

matches the whole string (and captures it - if you don't know what that means, that probably means it doesn't matter to you).

Given a longer string (which I made up)

```
Dog_NN Arms_NNS folded_VVN ,_, burp_VV
```

it still matches the part you want.

If the _VVN part is optional, you can use

```
(\w+_(?:NN|NNS) (?:\w+_(?:VBG|VVN) )?,_,)
```

which matches either witout, or with exactly one, word_VVN / word_VBG part.

---

Your more general questions:

I find it hard to explain how these things work.  I'll try to explain the constituent parts:

- \w matches word characters - characters you'd normally expect to find in words
- \w* matches one-or-more of them
- (NN|NNS) means "match NN or NNS"
- ?: means "match but don't capture" - suggest googling what capturing means in relation to regexes.
- ? alone means "match 0 or 1 of the thing before me - so x? would match "" or "x" but not "xx".
- None of the characters in ,_, are special, so we can match them just by putting them in the regex.

One problem with your regex is that \w will not match a comma (only "word characters").

I don't know what [\w-] does.  Looks a bit weird.  I think it's probably not valid, but I don't know for sure.

My solution assumes there is exactly one space, and nothing else, between your tagged words.

Comment: I didn't post the information here because it's complicated and I didn't know what you need. "Antconc embedded tags. You are looking to find these. The input would be like this.

her_PP$ voice_NN an_DT exact_JJ duplicate_NN
Only then in a larger body of text and you don't know the actual words, you just know the _XX tags.

you want to consider which characters are allowed in between the words. Could be any character that isn't a word character to allow periods, commas, quotes, colons, etc. 

Combined this would amount to this:

[\w-]+_PP\$\W+[\w-]+_NN\W+[\w-]+_DT\W+[\w-]+_JJ\W+[\w-]+_NN

Comment: You need to post here whatever is needed to answer the question, please. Make it as easy as you can for people to help you :-)

Comment: Did what I just added make sense?

Comment: I'm struggling to work out what you want, sorry. That looks almost nothing like what you originally asked for.  Try writing the question clearly, taking out any stuff not related to the question. It would be better to edit the original question, because the formatting will make it clearer what you're asking.

Comment: I thought I did write the question clearly, so I'm struggling to know what you want me to write. :) I'm working on something that labels each word by its part of speech (a noun is _NN, so it might appear as dog_NN). I am trying to create a regex that will pull out a string of these _TAGs so that I can do a grammar analysis. For example, "her voice an exact duplicate" (which is tagged her_PP$ voice_NN an_DT exact_JJ duplicate_NN), could be found with [\w-]+_PP\$\W+[\w-]+_NN\W+[\w-]+_DT\W+[\w-]+_JJ\W+[\w-]+_NN. Now in my question, I'm trying to find something new. Is that clearer?

Comment: Are you trying to find any exact sequences of (NN or NNS),(VBG or VNN),(comma) ?  (I don't understand how commas would fit into your labelled text - your description of the format doesn't mention commas.)

Comment: Yes. For now. Later I will again change the tags, but the way that the regex works will be the same, so it won't matter format-wise if that makes sense. I thought that I did it right in my original regex, but it's not working and I'm sure I've just made a simple error that I can't find. And in answer to your comma question, commas are tagged _,

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer and once we've clarified that I've answered the right question, I'll edit your question :-)  If either my guess at your source string or my assumption about what you want out from it are wrong, please post correct versions.

Comment: _PM is not the tag for commas, so I changed it to _, (do I need a backslash or anything for that?), but it's not finding anything. I know that there are some in the body of text, though. What's the difference between your [\w+] and my original [\w-] ? I'm still learning. :)

Comment: Right, I can't be doing with any more guessing.  Could you edit your question, please, stating clearly your exact input string (an example is fine) and your expected output?  No more answers until you do that :-)  Model the format of the question after my answer, if it helps.

Comment: I rewrote the question according to your format. Does it make more sense? I'm  not trying to extract anything (if I understand what that means correctly), I'm just trying to FIND the things. When there is a match, it will highlight it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Say that I wanted to look for the same thing, but I wanted to say "find NN or NNS with or without VVN or VBG following but still with the comma" ? Is that possible to do?

Comment: Yes. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Actually, real quick, if you don't mind, I'm working on the regex you gave, and it's coming up as an error. When I follow our format and try something like (\w*_(?:NN|NNS) it says "the search term is not a valid regular expression." Any ideas what could be wrong or how we could get around that?

Comment: You haven't closed the bracket. Note that the opening bracket in my regexes is closed right at the end - the whole thing is inside ().

Comment: AH. You're right. Thanks! I knew it was something obvious.

Comment: I was the answerer from the previous question. I came up with `[\w-]+` to include hyphenated words like _mother-in-law_ etc. Python regexes support shorthand classes `\w` inside custom classes `[...]`. As well I came up with `\W+` as the "separator" between words in stead of requiring **1 space and 1 space only**. But seeing as apparently punctuation has it's own tags like `,_,` for commas this might not be the best approach.

Comment: Yeah I guess you could also have apostrophes in the words.  I put a fair bit of effort into getting the OP to ask the question she wanted answered and I think my answer addresses what she actually asks :-)