# Regex, applying or operation on target string

Tags: regex

I'm studying regex.
Is it possible to apply oring operator on target string?

for example, consider POS tagging.

given a sentence like "I like apple", 
I want to match it with regex "NP like NNG"

Since there exists part-of-speech for each word in the sentence,
given a regex "NP like NNG", 
8 possible target strings can be matched.
(I like apple, NP like apple, NP VV apple, NP VV NNG et al.)

I was wondering, is it possible to treat target string as (I|NP)(like|VV)(apple|NNG) so that
regex "NP like NNG" can be matched at once?

Comment: Is it a pattern for Stanford NLP `TokenSequencePattern`?

Answer (score 0):

You've already written almost the entire regex with `(I|NP)(like|VV)(apple|NNG)`

Only thing you need to account for is the spaces, you can do this with `\s` like so:

```
(I|NP)\s+(like|VV)\s+(apple|NNG)
```

See also this [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9hbowNBg4o3PpHYz)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think you misunderstood me. In my question, regex is "NP like NNG" and the target string is "I like Apple" with (I=>NP), (like=>VV), (Apple=>NNG) pairs.

Comment: Ah, I see, so NP, VV en NNG are categories of words (nouns, verbs, etc) and you wish to match words with the right category? This is not possible with regexes. Regexes purely look at sequence of characters but are not fit you look at meaning of a word within a context. I've answered a similar question though, here the input-text has "tags" that denote the category that _can_ be matched: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751807/translate-from-tag-format-to-regex-for-corpus